# Extract sequence of elements from a list in R

Tags: r

I am looking for a shorter expression for something like the following:

```
list(x[[1]],x[[2]],x[[3]],x[[4]])
```

I tried

```
list(x[[1:4]])
```

and

```
list(x[1:4])
```

but none of these do what the original expression does.

Comment: Please show a reproducible example, `x[1:4]` should work assuming `x <- list(1:4, 1:3, 1:2, 1:5, 1:6, 1:9)`

Comment: The list x contains linear regression models, assigned by, for example, `x[[1]]<-lm(y~z)`. Does that help?

Answer (score 3):

The simple approach is just:

```
x[[1:4]]
```

no need to wrap it in `list`.

If you need to do something a little more complicated, then `lapply` can be used as well (overkill for this, but I will show an example anyways in case it helps for other cases):

```
> x <- list()
> x[[1]] <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ ., data=iris)
> x[[2]] <- lm(Sepal.Width ~ ., data=iris)
> x[[3]] <- lm(Petal.Width ~ ., data=iris)
> x[[4]] <- lm(Petal.Length ~ ., data=iris)
> x[[5]] <- lm(Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width, data=iris)
> 
> test1 <- list(x[[1]], x[[2]], x[[3]], x[[4]])
> test2 <- x[1:4]
> test3 <- lapply(1:4, function(i) x[[i]])
> 
> identical(test1,test2)
[1] TRUE
> identical(test1,test3)
[1] TRUE
>
```